# TypeError: interaction.options.getSubCommand is not a function (discord.js v14)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. This code was working before in v13 but ever since I updated to v14 this code stopped working. I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: interaction.options.getSubCommand is not a function
```

my code (interactionCreate.js):

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
name: "interactionCreate",
/**
 * @param {Client} client
 * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
 */
async execute(interaction, client){
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
        //const error = require('../../util/errorEmbed.js')(interaction, "Invalid command name");
        if(!command) return interaction.reply({content: "Error", ephemeral: true})
        && client.commands.delete(interaction.commandName);
        command.execute(interaction, client);
    }
}
```

}

soundeffect.js:

```
const { CommandInteraction, ApplicationCommandType, Client } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
"name": "soundeffect",
"description": "Plays a sound effect in a voice channel.",
"type": ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
"options": [
    {
        "type": 1,
        "name": "bruh",
        "description": "Plays the bruh sound effect"
    },
    {
        "type": 1,
        "name": "whatthedogdoing",
        "description": "Plays the what the dog doing sound effect"
    },
    {
        "type": 1,
        "name": "ohmygod",
        "description": "Plays the oh my god sound effect"
    }
],
/**
 * 
 * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
 * @param {Client} client
 */
async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand) return;
    if(!interaction.member.voice.channelId) return await interaction.reply("You must be in a voice channel!");
    
    if(interaction.options.getSubCommand() === 'bruh') require('./soundEffect/playBruhSound')(interaction);
}
```

}

playBruhSound.js:

```
    const { CommandInteraction, ApplicationCommandType } = require("discord.js");
    const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource } = require('@discordjs/voice');

/**
 * 
* @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
*/
module.exports = (interaction) => {

    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    player.play(createAudioResource('../files/movie_1.mp3'));

    joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: interaction.member.voice.channelId,
        guildId: interaction.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    }).subscribe(player);

    await interaction.reply(`Played bruh sound effect in <#${interaction.member.voice.channelId}.`);
}
```

Comment: Vote to close as it's a typo. It should be `getSubcommand`, not `getSubCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

> Vote to close as it's a typo. It should be `getSubcommand`, not `getSubCommand`.

same as @Zsolt Meszaros mentioned